# Extern or extrn in B?

Tags: extern, b-lang

I have a confusion between two B keywords.

The official B reference manual uses `extrn` keyword, while Wikipedia and C use `extern`.

As I don't know any good B compiler for x86, I can't spellcheck using a compiler.

So, what's the correct way of writing extern keyword in B - `extern` or `extrn`?

Comment: The Wikipedia article was incorrect and has since been corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no B programmer, but I would say `extrn` is right.

Sources: [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3agWKntXMJb1wJ%3areptide.radiofreeomaha.net/2009/04/20/the-b-programming-language/&hl=nl&gl=nl&prmd=imvns&strip=1) and [here](http://progopedia.com/language/b/).
Source 1 even explicitly states:

> What’s different compared to C?
>
> - extrn keyword instead of extern keyword.